# Why is Python 3.4 still developed after the release of 3.5?

Tags: python, versioning, python-3.x

The lastest version of Python is 3.5.1. However, the latest release is 3.4.4. Why is 3.4.x still developed? Are there breaking changes in 3.5 with respect to 3.4?

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: Have you asked the python developers about their roadmap?

Comment: No, but to be honest I still think it is worth to have an answer here for the community.

Comment: I looked for the answer in the release notes, the python site and of course I googled it.

Comment: `Why is 3.4.x still developed?`: I can only guess.  You need to ask the people submitting changes.  `Can migrating from 3.4 to 3.5 be a painful process?` purely opinion (how painful is a question of what features you used and how they changed, if t all).  `Are we starting to see another fork of the language as with 2.x and 3.x?` Purely speculation - need to ask the python developers for their roadmap.

Comment: I reworded the questions to make them non opinion based

Comment: After the rewording this is no long opinion-based. Voting to reopen. (I removed one sentence from the question in order to make it unarguably non-opinion-based. Hint: "why would anyone do X?" is not a good question for P.SE).

Comment: @AndresF. fair enough. I guess the same thing is actually asked in a better way with my breaking changes question

Comment: @AndresF. since we in no way speak for python developers and your search is as good as mine - would you consider that 'Have the developers announced an intention to fork the language again as with 2.x and 3.x?' should be removed too?

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, good call. Go ahead!

Comment: @MichaelT, why? Someone can be in a distribution list and can be able to shred some light on it. Or actually, someone involved in development can be able to answer that.

Comment: @rgargente for questions that can only be properly answered by someone with inside knowledge, your best course of action to get the question answered would be ask that person or mailing list. Expecting them to come here and answer is unreasonable. Anyone without that information would either be answering a question incompletely or speculating - neither of which make for good answers. You will note neither of the answers you have gotten answer that subquestion.

Comment: @MichaelT, fair enough. Anyway, just because I ask it doesn't mean that I "expect" an answer or feel entitled to have one.

Comment: If your quesiton is "are there breaking changes between Python 3.4 and 3.5" then you should just ask that only.

Comment: @Brandin, no. My question is what you can see. There are breaking changes happens to be the most sensible answer so far. However no specific changes have been mentioned so far.

Comment: @rgargente If you really want to know, that's what the "release notes" are for. Some people just download the newest version without bothering to check why they should use the newest version. Others prefer to stay at the most stable version (i.e., only accept bugfixes). Because with extra features usually comes extra bugs.

Comment: @Brandin the 'breaking changes' question would be more applicable to Stack Overflow - it deals with implementation and debugging rather than software design and architecture. Listing differences between two versions would likely be too broad though.

Comment: So could someone please explain why is the question still closed after all the discussion and rewording? How is it not an appropiate question as it stands now?

Comment: @rgargente To answer your breaking changes question, you could submit to SO and ask if there is a program which compiles and runs on both Python 3.4 and Python 3.5, but which gives a different result in each environment. Be sure to set some ground rules to disallow "obvious" cases. For example, you can't just create a program that prints the Python version and then claim that that is a breaking change because it gives a different result in 3.5.

Answer (score 9):

For important software, it is common to support a release for multiple years. With Python, support is mostly in the form of bugfixes. You can see the changelog for the whole list of fixes between versions (see [3.5 full changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/changelog.html)).

Between versions such as 3.5 and 3.4, not only bugs were fixed but also new features were added. E.g. 3.5 added the `@` matrix multiplication operator, and async-await style coroutine support. Organizations may want a fully-patched system without the uncertainty implied by a new feature, after having tested that a specific Python version works for them.

Given a version number such as 3.5.1, this allows you to quickly recognize the level of compatibility: for Python version 3, that would be the 5th feature release, and the 1st bug fix release for that feature release. Similarly, the 2.x branch is not being developed further, and is stuck at `2.7.x`. However, this widely spread version will still receive bugfixes (currently at 2.7.11).

For further information, read the about the [Python Development Cycle in the *Developer Guide*](https://docs.python.org/devguide/devcycle.html).

Comment: I'd say paragraphs 1 and 3 are mostly superflous and don't adress the question. Nontheless, upvoted

Answer (score 3):

The same reason we receive updates to Windows 7 after the release of Windows 8, 8.1, 10.…

The same reason you can take your car to the dealer for a service and new tyres, even though it's ten years old. It would be a bit rubbish if you had to buy a whole new car every time you broke a tail light.

The same reason you can build a new porch at the front of your home instead of moving house.

Incremental updates and patches to older versions of software is a crucial part of maintaining a project; you can't just expect everyone to perform major upgrades every few weeks (each of which may come with its own dependency/interface breakages).

Comment: Totally agree. Python 3.5 hasn't even been out that long; it drops support for a small but significant platform; and if there is no pressing reason to upgrade (you don't intend to use the new features of the language, or whatever) then there's no reason to do so.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this really addresses the point of the question. They are just general ideas that we could say about any software but I am talking specifically about Python 3.4 and 3.5. I understand what you say but why would anyone stick to 3.4? Is changing to 3.5 considered a major update? You can't compare updating a package to installing a whole new OS. As I implied, I understand going from 2.x to 3.x can be a major issue. How is 3.4 to 3.5 similar? Could you be more specific or we just don't know?

Comment: @rgargente: I'm not a Python expert but I believe that, unlike in other projects, a "minor" version change in Python can in fact be API breaking. Certainly I've found plenty of scripts that work in Python 2.6 but not in 2.7, and vice versa. That's reason enough.

Comment: @TZHX could you be more specific about this: "it drops support for a small but significant platform"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, fair enough. Thank you for the clarification, but that confirms the answer is especulative in nature, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @rgargente there are things that work in Python 3.4.x that cause SyntaxError exceptions in 3.5, there are things in the API that have been removed. If you want to know a whole list of what has changed, there are [resources](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html) for that, but every project or developer will make the decision based on their own needs -- so Python, being a respectful and mature community, continue to support "older" versions.

Comment: @rgargente: It is somewhat, yes, but then that's another reason to keep support for slightly older versions for a while: to cater for as many use cases and opinions as possible ;)

Comment: @TZHX That should be an answer, not a comment. "There are breaking changes from 3.4 to 3.5, such as $CHANGE, therefore continuing support is needed for the 3.4 branch for those who can't or do not want to deal with said breaking changes". I'd upvote such an answer :)

Comment: @TZHX, me too! :)

Comment: Python 3.5 does not work on Windows XP. Python 3.4.x does. While Microsoft no longer supports Windows XP that does not mean IT consultants stopped supporting it. Some IT consultant support contracts were poorly written. Also being open source implied not being behelded to the whims of Operating System developers and distributor licensing renew requirements. What's the point of open source languages and apps if I have to upgrade an OS contract every year? Helps with job security but imposes the will of business onto the  free development communtiy.

Comment: @DevPlayer: Beholden

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit .beholden... now learned. I struggled with it.